# Change table class color when condition met PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I have a table on my intranet that shows dates of servicing.

I need to change my code so that when the next due date is near, the field turns amber (`<td class='warning'></td>`), and when the date is today or overdue, it goes red (`<td class='danger'></td>`).

How could I do this?

Comment: `I need to change my code` - show the code you need to change.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change your code, maybe you should give us your code in the first place ;)

Are you using plain PHP or any kind of templating engine ?
If not, it could look something like that :

```
<?php $class = $isOverdue ? 'danger' : 'warning'; ?>

<td class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
    ...
</td>
```

Comment: ` <td class='info'>" . date("dS  M Y", strtotime($lastServiced)) . "</td> `
` <td class='success'>" . date("dS M Y", strtotime($nextDue)) . "</td> `